# How to target a button with some matching text with selenium driver

Tags: python, selenium

I am really new to selenium python, and stuck on a problem that i cannot figure out. Please someone can help. I want to target this button and click it, but the problem is there is other button too on the page that have exactly same class id etc there is only 1 difference between these two buttons. that is

```
aria-label=""
```

The text inside aria-label that i want to click starts with

```
dislike this video
```

The text is dynamic but the starting is same only the number changes descrbied below. I just want to target this button and click it, as both buttons have exact same classes so i felt only this tag that can be targeted and clicked. I Can anyone tell me how to target the starting text even (dislike) would work. and click the button. Below is the button code.

```
<button is="paper-icon-button-light" id="button" class="style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer style-text" aria-label="dislike this video along with 14,279 other people" aria-pressed="false">
```

I tried this code and it works fine but only if the text is exact match

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[aria-label="dislike this video along with 14,279 other people"]').click()
```

So the number in the above tag changes , and it doesnt work.

in simple words, there are 2 buttons having exact same class etc , but i want to click on the second button. how to do that with selenium python ?

button 1  html code

```
<button is="paper-icon-button-light" id="button" class="style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer style-text" aria-label="like this video along with 31,427 other people" aria-pressed="false"><yt-icon class="style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="style-scope yt-icon"><g class="style-scope yt-icon">
    <path d="M1 21h4V9H1v12zm22-11c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2h-6.31l.95-4.57.03-.32c0-.41-.17-.79-.44-1.06L14.17 1 7.59 7.59C7.22 7.95 7 8.45 7 9v10c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h9c.83 0 1.54-.5 1.84-1.22l3.02-7.05c.09-.23.14-.47.14-.73v-1.91l-.01-.01L23 10z" class="style-scope yt-icon"></path>
  </g></svg></yt-icon><paper-ripple class="style-scope paper-icon-button-light circle">


<div id="background" class="style-scope paper-ripple" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
<div id="waves" class="style-scope paper-ripple"></div>
```

button 2 html code

```
<button is="paper-icon-button-light" id="button" class="style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer style-text" aria-label="dislike this video along with 14,279 other people" aria-pressed="false"><yt-icon class="style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="style-scope yt-icon"><g class="style-scope yt-icon">
    <path d="M15 3H6c-.83 0-1.54.5-1.84 1.22l-3.02 7.05c-.09.23-.14.47-.14.73v1.91l.01.01L1 14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h6.31l-.95 4.57-.03.32c0 .41.17.79.44 1.06L9.83 23l6.59-6.59c.36-.36.58-.86.58-1.41V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm4 0v12h4V3h-4z" class="style-scope yt-icon"></path>
  </g></svg></yt-icon><paper-ripple class="style-scope paper-icon-button-light circle">


<div id="background" class="style-scope paper-ripple" style="opacity: 0.00416;"></div>
<div id="waves" class="style-scope paper-ripple"></div>
```

Comment: You can use CSS but why not xpath? This would be easy since you have id. xpath - //*[@id="button"]

Comment: I can target it with xpath but the problem is there are 2 buttons. both have same id . If you read my question properly , i have mentioend 2 buttons having exact same classes id only difference is aria-label text

Comment: Did you try this - xpath - (//*[@id="button"]) [2]

Comment: Yeh i tried it and it didnt work. I tried the code below and i can click on the first button. button cannot click on 2nd button   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.style-scope.ytd-toggle-button-renderer.style-text').click()

Comment: I don't think you would be able to click the button simply with **`xml`** name space. As the **`d`** attribute is present you have to use **`svg`** namespace as well.

Answer (score 0):

You try with following css-

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[aria-label^="dislike this video"]').click()
```

or with xpath-

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[starts-with(@aria-label,"dislike this video")]').click()
```

Comment: I had already tried the first example but it doesnt work as its not matching the complete text. and tried the 2nd example now, but doesnt work too.

Comment: @BabarAli can you post the html code for the both buttons?

Comment: done, please check the main question . refresh the page. i have added code of both the buttons

Comment: It seems like toggle button. you can use id attribute to locate the element like driver.find_element_by_id("button").click(); have you tried it before? is id unique on the page?

Comment: yes i have tried with id, but the id is same for both the buttons .. so it clicks on the first button. I want to click on the 2nd button

Comment: try using xpath like (//button[@id="button"])[2]. it may works.

Comment: Yeh i tried it and it didnt work. I tried the code below and i can click on the first button. button cannot click on 2nd button   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.style-scope.ytd-toggle-button-renderer.style-text').click()

Comment: @BabarAli, What do you mean by *doesn't work*? You still click on the first button or get exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath-

```
(//*[@id="button"]/yt-icon)[2]
```

Comment: doesnt work. i can only click the first button with the following code   `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.ytd-toggle-button-renderer').click()`     how to target the 2nd button ?

Comment: cannot find element .. i will give you the link of the page ..  its basically a youtube video link. can be any youtube video page , for eg :  `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQgXKtPSzUI`    i need to click the downvote/dislike button on the page. i can click on the upvote/like .